# PHP not executing code from include

Tags: php, html

So from the code you can see that it should be echoing the points and username values that are stored in the includes php file. Well... It's not and I'm frustrated! Is there something I'm doings wrong or just not getting?

**config.php**

```
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT points FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$points = $row['points'];
```

**index.php**

```
    <?php include('config.php'); ?>
    <div id="container">
    <?php echo $points . $username; ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: As an aside, you appear to have an [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerability.

Comment: Have you checked to see if there are any results from the query?

Comment: @icktoofay I assume you mean the $username? Should I really have to escape a session value?

Comment: @Stax: Yes, unless it was sanitized before (which I doubt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<?php session_start(); ?>` before you access `$_SESSION`.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to add that to the config.php. Really helps to have a second pair of eyes to look things over.

Answer (score 0):

First check your output get properly from `mysql` query and `session_start();` write on top of `config.php` file.